# redirecting a url_for when having a website submit text

Tags: flask, http-post

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.form['nm']
        return redirect(url_for('user', usr=user))
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')


@app.route('/<usr>')
def user(usr):
    return "<h1>{usr}</h1>
```

For my login.html page:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Login Page {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<form action='#' method='post'>
   <p>Name:</p>
   <p><input type='text' name='nm' /></p>
   <p><input type='submit' value='submit' /></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

So when I go to the login page and type some name what happens is

[image]

instead of displaying the name I typed. Can someone tell me what my issue is?

Answer (score -1):

You must use double brace "{{ }}" with Jinja2 expressions. You can fix it by editing user route like this:

```
@app.route('/<usr>')
def user(usr):
    return "<h1>{{usr}}</h1>
```